# Adding new structure to array of structures after checking some variables

Tags: arrays, c, structure

I have an array of structures and I would like to compare two variables of structure with already existing structures in array if there is any match then just update certain structure in array. If no match found i want add new structure to array.

```
int number=0;

struct my_struct
{
  enum book_status status;                                         
  enum book_id id;                                  
  enum book_type type;                                              
  int bookcode;                                                        
  char* status_msg;                                                  
};

struct my_struct book_list[25];

struct my_struct newbook( enum book_id id,
                    enum book_type type,
                    enum book_status status,
                    int bookcode,
                    char* status_msg )
{

struct my_struct this_book;

this_book.status = status;
this_book.type =type;
this_book.id = id;
this_book.bookcode = bookcode;


if(checkbook(enum book_type type, int code))
  {
    book_list[number]= this_book;
  }else
  {
    book_list[number] =this_book;
  }
 return this_book;
 }


//function to check all books before adding 
struct my_struct* checkBookexists(enum book_type type, int code)
{
  int i = 0;
  // Loop trough all books and check for
    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    if(book_list[i].type == type && book_list[i].bookcode  == bookcode)
        return &book_list[i];
  ++number;
  return NULL;
 }
```

This way i am able check book struct and add them to array of books structs. I am not able to start at book_list[0] because i am increasing the number at start so it is starting from book_list[1].

If i dont increase number there then always book_list[0] is replacing without duplicate or missing.

I want to add new structures from 0 and avoid duplicates.

can anyone help me how to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

1. *number* is not initialized but used, initialize it with 0
2. remove the asterisk at the end of *char status_msg;* in your *struct my_struct*
3. is the array *book_list* initialized with default values (probably zeroed out)?
4. function *newbook* does not return any value and contains some useless dots
5. the result of *checkbook* in the function *newbook* is irrelevant, because no matter what, *this_book* will be assigned to *book_list[number]*
6. provide a working example